# Prove or disprove:  if A is a subset of B and B is not a subset of C, then A is not a subset of C

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Prove or disprove:  if A is a subset of B and B is not a subset of C, then A is not a subset of C.

I know it is false for the counter example:

A = {1, 2}

B = {1, 2, 3, 4}

C = {1, 2, 6, 5}

How can I prove that mathematically?

Comment: All you need to do to prove that something is false is to provide a counterexample. It seems you've done that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just did; it's called a [Counterexample](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterexample).

You simply note that these particular $A$, $B$, and $C$ satisfy the hypotheses ("$A$ is a subset of $B$ and $B$ is not a subset of $C$"), but fail to satisfy the proposed conclusion ("$A$ is not a subset of $C$"). So the proposed implication cannot always hold. This disproves the assertion.

Answer (score 0):

There exist an element x that is a member of set A and since set A is a subset of set B, then that element x is also a member of set B.

Since set B is not a subset of set C that there does not exist an element x which is a member of set C, therefore element x is not in set C

Therefore element x is a member of set A but not an element in set C therefore set A is not a subset of set C.

Answer (score -1):

A is  the subset of B given:
B is not the subset of C given:
Let x be an arbitrary element such that x belongs to A than we have to show that x doesn't belong to C
=>xEA (:. given)
=>xEB  (A is subset of B)
=>x doesn't belong to C  (B is not the subset of C)
but x is an arbitraray element of A hence proved that A is not the subset of C

Comment: This is incorrect. "$A$ is not a subset of $C$" does **not** mean that elements of $A$ are not elements of $C$. "$A$ is not a subset of $C$" means "there exists *at least one* $x$ such that $x\in A$ and $x\notin C$. Your implication that $x$ does not belong to $C$ because it belongs to $B$ is incorrect, based on that misunderstanding of what "not a subset" means.

Comment: You correctly proved that "If $A$ is a subset of $B$, and $B$ is **disjoint** from $C$, then $A$ is disjoint from $C$." However, the problem is different.

Answer (score -1):

You can say that if $A$ is included in $B \cap C$ then it is obviously a subset of $B$ and $C$ by definition of the intersection. 
But $B$ need not to be a subset of $C$ for $B \cap C$ to be non empty hence for $A$ to be non empty. Your example illustrate this quite well